# Assets not being required by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

For some reason, the js files under app/asset/javascripts folder are no longer being requested by the rails application.

I have enabled assets in `application.rb`

I have these lines in `application.js`:

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

with proper use of the blank lines.

And I have included this line in my `application.html.erb` file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

I have `application.js, jquery.js, jquery-ui.js, prototype.js` and some other js files in the `javascripts` folder.
But when I access those js files in Firefox firebug, the content are different from that in the folder. I keep getting the message: `Served asset /xxx.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)`.

It is so frustrating and I really need some help.
Thank you in advance!

I am using

Rails version: 3.2.7

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p194

gem version: 1.8.24

Thin server

UPDATE:
I have used `rake assets:clean` and this never happened again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is beacuse to you have this precompiled files in public dir

try adding this to `development.rb`

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: No, that still didn't solve the problem, but I found another way around by changing the value of `config.assets.version ` , it's probably not the right way to do this, but it works. Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: UPDATE: I have used 'rake assets:clean' and this never happened again!

Comment: @Newbie, yeah thats what i meant by having precompiled assets from public dir. 'rake assets:clean` delete all compiled assets from public.
so in development if you want to call assests directly from app/assets/ you need to set `config.serve_static_assets = false`